# How to run a command automatically everytime I log into a remote server via ssh without disconnecting the session

Tags: linux, centos

I am trying to have my ssh set up using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522647/run-ssh-and-immediately-execute-command/18522811#18522811)

I am using the command:

`sshpass -p myrealpassword ssh byteme@byteme.com.au -t 'cd web && git status'`

It is working OK and I am able to run a command everytime I log in but I get an error message:

`Connection to byteme.com.au closed.`

right after running the remote command.

**How can I run this command without getting kicked out of my ssh session?**

Comment: maybe to use daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a command to SSH the way you're doing, it does not run a shell, it runs only the command you passed. You can try to attach to a "new" shell by adding a `&& bash -i` to the end of your command, though that will give you a shell with some unexpected behaviors, or you can simply add those commands to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files to be executed at login, and not run them as part of the SSH command.

Comment: `sshpass -p myrealpassword ssh byteme@byteme.com.au -t 'cd web && git status && bash -i'`worked. Thanks. Is there a way I can compare the two shells?